# Transfer windows 10 pro upgrade to new computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10, upgrade

Ok, so I paid the $99 to upgrade my laptop from windows 10 home to pro. I bought the upgrade in the windows store because that's the only way I figured I could do it.

If that laptop dies and I get a new laptop, will I be able to transfer that upgrade? What if the laptop dies and Lenovo sends me a new one? Will the new one be entitled to my upgrade to windows 10 pro?

Comment: No, the underlying license is still considered OEM, which is tied to the original hardware for life.

Comment: No; All you did was upgrade the OEM Home license to a Professional license.  You would need to purchase a retail license, revert back to home, for you to be eligible to use that upgrade but the price delta between home and professional isn't that big your better off just getting Windows 10 Pro.  A new laptop would come with its own Windows 10 license

Comment: I cannot find any information on the transfer rights of an Easy Upgrade version of Windows, though as mentioned above it sounds like all you have done is convert a lower OEM version to a higher OEM version which still has no transfer rights. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/how-can-you-tell-if-windows-10-is-oem-or-retail/b8f9eed4-8e41-4552-ba7f-d4f3b08fd1f9 can you run the slmgr command using the method mentioned at the bottom of that link and tell us whether it claims to be retail or OEM? Retail would have transfer rights, OEM would not.

Comment: SLMGR doesn't say anything about it. Gives a message invalid combination of command parameters.